# Cocoa: get position of an NSStatusBar item

Tags: cocoa, nsstatusbar

How can I get the position or frame of an `NSStatusBar` item?

Comment: Legal solution is in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11520308/956170).

Answer (score 1):

1. There is undocumented `[statusBarItem _window]` method.
2. Assign a view to the item, and then use view's `window` method.

There is no documented way to get it without setting a view. And when status bar item has a view, you have to draw title/image/everything yourself.