# Follow an NSStatusItem with a window - incorrect position when switching to a taller display

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

The problem: I have to follow the app's NSStatusItem popup/window right beneath it.

The general solution for this (like it's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504696/get-notification-of-nsstatusitem-frame-change/11520308#11520308) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301701/how-to-get-the-on-screen-location-of-an-nsstatusitem)) is to add a custom view to the NSStatusItem and get the view's window's frame (statusItem.view.window.frame), and connect to move event through NSWindowDidMoveNotification notification of the statusItem.view.window.

This solution works 99% unless the user connects an external display which is taller than the previous display (for example a Mac Book user connects an external monitor), in this case the statusItem.view.window.frame will be incorrect, X coordinate will be actually correct but the Y coordinate will be the same as it was in the smaller screen!

I've checked and most of the menubar apps which have a popup window when you click the status item are misplaced just like I've described.

My solution was to don't use the Y coordinate from this frame but use the corresponding NSScreen's visibleFrame's height like this:

```
NSScreen *screenWithMenuBar = [[NSScreen screens] objectAtIndex:0];
    if( screenWithMenuBar ) {
        // correct the top position by the 'screen with the MenuBar's height
        //  workaround: without this the window will be off-placed when the user plugs in an external display,
        //      a display with more height
        NSRect visibleRect = [screenWithMenuBar visibleFrame];
        originPoint.y = visibleRect.size.height + visibleRect.origin.y;
    }
```

As stated in the official Apple documentation [the first screen should be always the screen which contains the menubar](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/Reference/Reference.html) so it should work, but it seems too much of a hack for me.

Have you guys experienced this bug? Have you found a better solution?

Comment: Does getting the new value of `[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] thickness]` work?

Comment: @KeithSmiley it's always the same (the menubar's thickness doesn't change when switching to an external monitor) - sorry, maybe I don't understand what you suggest - how should this help?